# SQL query for maximum value and maximum date

Tags: sql

I Need help with a query to identify records in a table based on a maximum value of a column and the maximum date as well.

In the example below I would only want to display in the results; the record for account_id 1234567  with the SEQ_nmbr "6" (because it's the maximum seq_nmbr) and change_dt 04/10/2003 (because it's the maximum date)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `row_number` ordered against your row(s) and select only the top matching row. Presumably your date column is a `date` data type and not a string.

```
select Account_Id, Change_dt, Seq_Nmbr, Actn_CD from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by seq_nmbr desc, change_dt desc) rn
  from Table
)t
where rn=1
```

Comment: select Account_Id, Change_dt, Seq_Nmbr, Actn_CD from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by seq_nmbr desc, change_dt desc) rn
  from "my table name"
)t
where rn=1

Comment: I get the following error after adding "my table name" to the query.                                             Error: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "," was found following ",".  Expected tokens may include:  "FROM INTO".  SQLSTATE=42601
 (State:42601, Native Code: FFFFFF98)

Comment: @baller_88 You probably have a typo. The code works fine, see [this working DB2 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=ce5867823cb6f40f8a2756d119bfd7be). If you still have trouble edit your question and add a reproduceable example of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the max values for each ACCOUNT_ID you should use [Group By clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The group by clause will return query result into groups of rows, usually for the purpose of performing one or more aggregations on each group.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID,MAX(SEQ_NMBR),MAX(CHANGE_DT)
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
```

And [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) you have some examples.

Otherwise if you want to get the full row you will need to use the [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)() function with over and order by you column preference. Then filter the first result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by account_id
      order by seq_number desc, change_dr desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I receive the following error when I enter in "my table name" following the From.                Error: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "," was found following ",".  Expected tokens may include:  "FROM INTO".  SQLSTATE=42601
 (State:42601, Native Code: FFFFFF98)

Comment: select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by contract_id
      order by seq_number desc, change_dt desc) as rn
  from "my table name"
)x
where rn = 1

Comment: It probably depends on the SQL dialect you are using. You didn't mention the database, but this code works pretty much on any database. See example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qWAJLpXCTT7HySbXJPk8pK/0

Comment: the database was db2

Comment: @baller_88 Works well in DB2 as well. See running example at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c85e3fe9f58ff6752972d01dd5c4bb6a

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running this query on Oracle or any similar database with access to analytical functions, you can use the below query to find the maximum SEQ_NMBR and date for each account -

```
select distinct ACCOUNT_ID
, max(SEQ_NMBR) over (partition by ACCOUNT_ID) as MAX_SEQ_NMBR
, max(CHANGE_DT) over (partition by ACCOUNT_ID) as MAX_CHANGE_DT 
from Table
```

Comment: and if I only wanted to find the max seq nmbr for each account?  so not finding the max change_dt.

Comment: Then simply remove the max(CHANGE_DT)... part from the code. Essentially it would look like below `select distinct ACCOUNT_ID, max(SEQ_NMBR) over (partition by ACCOUNT_ID) as MAX_SEQ_NMBR from Table`